# Jquery - Hyperlink cannot be click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table, then table row can be clicked. But some cell, cannot be clicked if there is a hyperlinks. Because if i allow it, there will be 2 action. Action on tr click and action on hyperlink click.

so i decide to disable thats cell.

```
$("tbody").on("click", "tr td:last-child", function() { 
   return false;
});
```

But when i do this,, my hyperlink cannot be clicked.

This is my full script

```
$("tbody").on("click", "tr td:last-child", function() { 
    return false;
});
$("tbody").on("click", "tr td:nth-last-child(2)", function() { 
    return false;
});
$("tbody").on("click", "tr", function() {   
    console.log('tr click');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1twzdm9c/18/

In my version, i cant click tr and hyperlink,, but in jsfiddle, im still can click tr but hyperlink cannot wont effect.

Comment: Try searching for `preventDefault()`

Comment: Try using :

$("tbody").on("click", "tr td:last-child a", function() { 
   return false;
});

Comment: my tr click work,, but my hyperlink click not work,, i want my hyperlink click work..

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit, is there a click event attached to the hyperlinks, or are the links just redirecting?

Comment: I have add my full script. maybe you already have an idea what i'm doing

Comment: You can solve this by removing the click on tr and give all the td's without a hyperlink a special class like class="clickable" and react on that.

Comment: I update my question with jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just not bind the click in first place

```
$("tbody").find("tr td").not(":last,:nth-last-child(2)").on("click", function() {   
    console.log('tr click');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/27jygkqx/

Answer (score 0):

add this attribute in non clickable td

```
<td data-click="false">....
 <td data-click="false">...

<script>  
    $("tbody").on("click", "tr td:not([data-click='false'])", function() {   
        console.log('tr click');
    });
</script>
```